# Configure application integration with ufw firewall

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I've read the ubuntu developer docs regarding the ufw [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/firewall.html), but couldn't find what I was looking for. It allows me to set rules for controlling in/out traffic based on source IP or port numbers, but what I want is to restrict based on applications. For example:

> (1) only firefox.exe allowed to communicate on port 80 - outgoing
>
> (2) only apache.exe/httpd.exe allowed to communicate on port 80 - incoming, etc.

(Hope you get what I'm trying to imply - this is possible in windows firewall).

I'm not able to see how I can achieve this with ufw firewall? Or is there a better alternative to ufw which is able to do this on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-implemented the firewall entirely from scratch using iptables. Iptables gives more control and the rules are very simple to assign such as:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o ppp0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT #http
```

Having do so, I've bid farewell to the ufw firewall:

```
sudo apt-get remove ufw
```